# OpenFOAM user compilations

Tags: docker, compilation, singularity-container, openfoam

This is my first question in Stack overflow. I am studying master mechanical engineering.
I have started Project Work. I have never worked with C++ or OpenFoam before, sothat i am a little bit lost and need just directions and suggestions.

The first Problem that i need to find Solution of it,

**what is the right way for compilation ? how OpenFOAM user compilations work and how to compile your own projects ? whether and how user functions can be compiled and used in OpenFOAM when using Docker or Singularity ? **

I am using Linux/Ubuntu and Openfoam 1612+.

Thanks in advance

I have not tried any thing yet and i am expecting to find suggestion and easy explanation for beginner. It would be very Helpful to start the Project in the best way.